# __del__() with args in additional to self

Tags: python, destructor

I've a Python program as follows:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.n=n
    def __del__(self,n):
        print('dest',self.n,n)
def b():
    d=a('d')
    c=a('c')
    d.__del__(8)
    
b()
```

Here, I have given a parameter `n` in `__del__()` just to clear my doubt. Its output :

```
$ python des.py 
dest d 8
Exception ignored in: <function a.__del__ at 0xb799b074>
TypeError: __del__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'
Exception ignored in: <function a.__del__ at 0xb799b074>
TypeError: __del__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'
```

In classical programming languages like C++ we can't give parameters for the destructor. To know if it is applicable for python too, I've executed this program. Why does the interpreter allow the parameter `n` to be given as a parameter for the destructor? How can I specify value for that `n` then? As a try to give an argument for `__del__()` and it goes fine. But without it how can I specify the value for `n`?

Comment: Why would it *prevent* that? Python is dynamically typed, you can define those methods however you like but may (as in this case) see errors at runtime if you get it wrong.

Comment: Basically, you can't have an extra parameter for `__del__`, although the language doesn't enforce this rule strictly; a `__del__` method with an extra paramater can still be called directly, it just doesn't function as a proper `__del__` method should when you use the `del` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You can *define* the `__del__` method with an argument, as you've shown. And if you call the method yourself, you can pass in a value, just like you can with any other method. But when the interpreter calls `__del__` itself, it's not going to pass anything, and there will be an exception raised.

However, because `__del__` methods are often called in precarious situations, like when the interpreter is shutting down, Python doesn't stop everything if one raises an exception. Instead, it just prints out that it's ignoring the exception and keeps doing what it was doing already. This is why you see two "Exception ignored" messages, as your `d` and `c` objects get cleaned up.

It's unclear to me what you *actually* want your `__del__` method to do with the `n` value you were passing in. Your example was a trivial case, usually there's nothing useful you can do there. Indeed, it's only rarely a good idea to write a `__del__` method for a class. There are better ways of doing resource allocation, like the context manager protocol (which uses `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods).

Answer (score 0):

you cannot. pre-defined dunder methods (methods with leading and trailing double underscore) like `__del__` have a fixed signature.

If you define them with another signature, then when python calls them using the non-dunder interface (`del`, `len`, ...), the number of arguments is wrong and it fails.

To pass `n` to `del`, you'll have to define it as an object member.

Comment: See python docs on [`Special method names`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) and [`__del__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)

Answer (score 0):

Python objects become a candidate for garbage collection when there are no more references to them (object tagging), so you do not need to create such a destructor.

If you want to add optional arguments to a method, it's common to set them to `None` or an empty tuple `()`

```
    def other_del(self, x=None):
        ...
```